# In order to figure the factorial of an integer, say, k, I must write a statement kfact = kfact *i. and I do not get why

Tags: c, loops

I am sort of self-learning the C language.

```c
for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
    kfact = kfact * i;
```

Using the mathematical formula to calculate the factorial was tried.

`n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)....*1`, but I do not get how it correlates with the above mentioned code.

```c
int k, kfact, i;
kfact = 1;

for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
    kfact=kfact*i;
printf("\n %d factorial is %d",k,kfact);
return 0;
```

Comment: Would it be easier to see the correlation if you wrote your formula as `n! = 1 * ... * (n-2) * (n-1) * n`?

Comment: While theoretical knowledge is great and prevents one from going down the wrong paths, sometimes debugging the code and executing it step by step provides the needed "AHA" moment. Have you tried running the code (for real or in your head)?

Comment: Note that 32-bit integers can only store up to 12! and 64-bit integers can only store up to 20!  Anything bigger requires `double` or multi-precision integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you're looking at is not computing the factorial using your
`n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)....*1` formula but rather on the equivalent `n! = (n-1)! * n` formula.

It starts off with the factorial of 0, which is 1 and then, in each iteration, computes the factorial of `i` as the previous factorial `(i-1)!` times `i`.

So, `kfact` is first `0!`, then `1!`, then `2!` and so on. After all the iteration steps you end up with `k!` in your `kfact` variable.

Comment: sincerest of gratitude for taking your time to provide me with this help. so much so that i'm almost in two minds about it, to query on further, do not wish to impose... but, i am in bit of a fix even now.so, if sir/ma'am doesn't mind, could you elucidate more on why it must start off  with 0! or 1. kfact has indeed been assigned a value of 1. but, i just haven't managed to gain insight on why.

Comment: You can just as easily start with `kfact = 24` and initialize your loop as `for(i=5;i<=k;i++)`, and you would compute the factorial of any number above 4... You start with 1, or `0!` because that is the smallest value for which the factorial is defined. First you determine the initial value of `i` that makes sense, then you determine the initial value of `kfact` that makes the algorithm work, (There are many contributors to the site, so the "do not wish to impose" preamble is unnecessary. Best to keep the comments short and to the point!)